# Is there a way to find out if A is a submatrix of B?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, numpy, matrix

I give quotation mark because what I mean is for example:

```
B = [[1,2,3,4,5],
     [6,7,8,9,10],
     [11,12,13,14,15],
     [16,17,18,19,20]]
```

suppose we select row 2,4 and col 1,3, the intersections will give us

```
A = [[6,8],
     [16,18]]
```

My question is suppose I have A and B, is there a way that I can find out which rows and cols are selected from B to give A?

By the way it would be best if you can give the answer in python/numpy. But just in math or in other programming language will be fine as well.

Comment: Is `[[6,8,9],[16,18,19]]` a valid sub matrix? (In other words, are you potentially looking for a list of indices on each axis, or only a start/stop/step slice?)

Comment: Also, should we assume you can figure out the obvious brute force solution, so it's not worth mentioning (at least without an argument that nothing more efficient is possible)?

Comment: Do you assume that rows/columns can be repeated in the matrix `A`? Do you assume that the rows and columns appear in the same order in `B` and in `A`?

Comment: You really don't need the quotes, as what you describe here is actually called a [submatrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Submatrix)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a very hard combinatorial problem. In fact the [Subgraph Isomorphism Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) can be reduced to your problem (in case the matrix `A` only has 0-1 entries, your problem is exactly a subgraph isomorphism problem). This problem is known to be NP-complete.

Here is a recursive backtracking solution which does a bit better than brute-forcing all possible solutions. Note that this still takes exponential time in the worst case. However, if you assume that a solution exists and that there are no *ambiguities* (for example that all the entries in `B` are distinct), this finds the solution in linear time.

```
def locate_columns(a, b, offset=0):
    """Locate `a` as a sublist of `b`.

    Yields all possible lists of `len(a)` indices such that `a` can be read
    from `b` at those indices.
    """
    if not a:
        yield []
    else:
        positions = (offset + i for (i, e) in enumerate(b[offset:])
                     if e == a[0])
        for position in positions:
            for tail_cols in locate_columns(a[1:], b, position + 1):
                yield [position] + tail_cols


def locate_submatrix(a, b, offset=0, cols=None):
    """Locate `a` as a submatrix of `b`.

    Yields all possible pairs of (row_indices, column_indices) such that
    `a` is the projection of `b` on those indices.
    """
    if not a:
        yield [], cols
    else:
        for j, row in enumerate(b[offset:]):
            if cols:
                if all(e == f for e, f in zip(a[0], [row[c] for c in cols])):
                    for r, c in locate_submatrix(a[1:], b, offset + j + 1, cols):
                        yield [offset + j] + r, c
            else:
                for cols in locate_columns(a[0], row):
                    for r, c in locate_submatrix(a[1:], b, offset + j + 1, cols):
                        yield [offset + j] + r, c

B = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19,20]]
A = [[6,8], [16,18]]

for loc in locate_submatrix(A, B):
    print loc
```

This will output:

```
([1, 3], [0, 2])
```

Comment: But it doesn't work when B = [[1,6,3,8,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19,20]]

Comment: Do you keep `A` to still be `[[6,8], [16,18]]`? In this case `A` is not a submatrix of `B` and the program does not output anything. Which is the expected output.

Comment: @Thibaut It actually forms a submatrix if you take the second and forth rows and columns of `B`.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to know is  which rows and cols are selected from B to give A and do not care about efficiency here is a brute force way that stores the results in an array `res` res[N] tells all locations of A[N] in B. Works even if A[N] exists in multiple locations of B.

```
B = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]
A = [[6,8], [16,18]]
res = []

for subsetIndex, subset in enumerate(A):
    k = []
    res.append(k)
    for supersetIndex, superset in enumerate(B):
        loc = []
        try:
            loc = [(supersetIndex, superset.index(item)) for item in subset]
            k.append(loc)
            print A[subsetIndex], "is at ", loc, "in B"
        except ValueError:
            pass
print res
```

output:

```
[6, 8] is at  [(1, 0), (1, 2)] in B
[16, 18] is at  [(3, 0), (3, 2)] in B
result =  [[[(1, 0), (1, 2)]], [[(3, 0), (3, 2)]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are all/most of the values in the matrix unique IE: They only appear once in matrix B?

The more unique the values the better the improvement you can make over subgraph isomorphism (SI). If all values are **unique**, then you can just do a reverse look-up on each value to determine it's row/column pair, union the list of rows and columns (separately).

Result is a simple `O(N)` algorithm, where `N = number of rows * number of columns`. Of course, the less unique the values, the more false positives you get that need checking and the closer you get to SI and the less simple things get.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute-force solution, if that's all you need:

```
rows = [i for aa in A for i,bb in enumerate(B) if np.in1d(aa, bb).all()]
cols = [i for aa in A.T for i,bb in enumerate(B.T) if np.in1d(aa, bb).all()]

submatrix = B[np.ix_(rows, cols)]
```

It's checking every row of `A` against every row of `B` to make sure all elements of the submatrix are present. Then, it does the same thing for the columns.

You could speed up the column-finding part by restricting it to only the relevant rows:

```
cols = [i for aa in A.T for i,bb in enumerate(B[rows].T) if np.equal(aa, bb).all()]
```

Comment: Wait a second... it doesn't actually check that the elements found are at correct positions, does it?

Comment: True, it just checks that they exist. This method will break if you need to deal with repeated elements.