# Determine indexes where A is a submatrix of matrix B

Tags: python, matrix, contains, submatrix, inclusion

I'm coding in python and I would like to know how I can get the indexes of a matrix A where the matrix B is contained in A. For example, if we have

```
A = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]
```

and

```
B = [[2,3],
     [5,6]]
```

Then it returns indexes `([0,0,1,1], [1,2,1,2])`, where the first list corresponds to x-axis, and the second to the y-axis. Or something like this.

Thank you for yor help !

Comment: If there are elements in `B` that are not in `A`, what results do you expect?

Comment: A False, or a None, or an empty tuple. Actually it is not exactly the function isin, as I want to have a subset of matrix A which is B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70315562/efficient-way-to-find-if-a-matrix-is-sub-matrix-of-another-one) to find if a matrix is a submatrix of another one.

Then, you can get the coordinates of each element exploiting the NumPy `where` function as:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.linspace(1, 9, 9).reshape([3, 3])
B = np.asarray([2, 3, 5, 6]).reshape([2, 2])

submatrix_tuple_coord = [list(np.where(A==b)) for bb in B for b in bb]
submatrix_xy = [[int(x), int(y)] for x, y in submatrix_tuple_coord]

# Return a list of list with the row-column indices
submatrix_xy 
>>> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
```